# Typescript best practice for "Types of parameters 'X' and 'X' are incompatible"

Tags: typescript

I have a question in typescript and want to know the best way in this situation

[demo-link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBDIKMjJBhLWiOBiIYQAb0UJU4DMg%20SuqEonGYAG5WWJmJz%20uxENJvoKAL7k7bfalLADy1AaXhZJVq0Gg0hp8S5oAAFAR6YyuXSyAzhAAfOimwQAbQAugBKUAAXgAfKAdPAKNxFLLFAhOIIaPBVY0AKJkNhkfIq%20qND2gDWjbW62D6432832t1e1NCzWNQTwdwBaDwZg5y2MgLs5AuoWyoMhsNJSOcJUAaQTXZTaa1Or1%20VrVoL3rTJdDNAIKZNdeEDGEFqtgpKM7LFarNYIDY5zZKraAA)

```
// Params and Option are defined by third-party lib so it cannot be changed
interface Params {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Option {
  callback:  (params: Params | Params[]) => void
}

// Here is my code
const optionError:Option = {
  // in this case, the type of params must be Params
  callback:(params: Params) => { // Type '(params: Params) => void' is not assignable to type '(params: Params | Params[]) => void'.
    console.log(params.name)
    console.log(params.age)
  }
}

const optionOK:Option = {
  callback:(params) => {
    const p = params as Params; // Don't want to define a same parameter, what else can I do?
    console.log(p.name)
    console.log(p.age)
  }
}
```

I dont't want to define a same parameter, is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that's what you're looking for, but this should solve your issue:

```
interface Params {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Option {
  callback:  (params: Params | Params[]) => void
}

const optionError:Option = {
  callback:(params: Params | Params[]) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(params)) {
      console.log(params.name)
    }
  }
}

const optionOK:Option = {
  callback:(params: Params | Params[]) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(params)) {
      console.log(params.name)
    }
  }
}
```

We're typing the callback params as it should be, and then checking if the params is of type Params or Params[] by using Array.isArray(). And typescript figures out that if it's not an array, it is Params.

Also, avoid using `params as Params` as much as possible, you're outpassing typescript typings and that can lead to runtime errors if you're not entirely sure that the passed argument will be of type Params

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me. I will  check the type of `params`  before I use it.

Answer (score 0):

THis is because of contravariance.

There is an **UNSAFE** trick, which allows you to get rid of TypeScript errors. You just need to convert your `callback` property to a method (get rid of arrow function).

According to TS docs, TS methods are bivariant.

```js
interface Params {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Option {
  callback(params: Params | Params[]): void // change is here
}

const optionError: Option = {
  callback: (params: Params) => {
    console.log(params.name)
  }
}

const optionOK: Option = {
  callback: (params: Params[]) => {
    params.map(e => e) // ok
  }
}
```

However this is **SUPER UNSAFE**. If you want it to make safe, use `@jeremynac`'s answers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is "best practice", but if your intention is to say that to comply with the `Option` type you need to implement the callback to accept `Params` or `Params[]` (or maybe both) you need to explicitly state that:

```
interface Params {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface OptionWithParams {
  callback:  (params: Params) => void
}

interface OptionWithParamsArray {
  callback:  (params: Params[]) => void
}

type Option = OptionWithParamsArray|OptionWithParams;
```

Then all the following are valid:

```
const optionOk1:Option = {
  callback:(params: Params) => {
    console.log(params.name)
  }
}


const optionOk2:Option = {
  callback:(params: Params[]) => {
    console.log(params[0].name)
  }
}
const optionOk3:Option = {
  callback:(params: Params|Params[]) => {
    console.log('It\'s all good');
  }
}
```

The last case should work as well if you allow implict `any` but you shouldn't need that.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBDIKMjJBhLWiOBiIYQAb0UJU4DMg%20SuqEonGYAG5WWJmJz%20uxENJvoKAL7k7bfalLADy1AanHAuzpZAZzKFtWg0GkNPiXNAAAoCPTGVytTqAJSgAC8AD5QDp4BRuIpZYoKQqaSgVfVGhrYrbGRUyNq8KAWSV9YbjaaLVaCnRUwBtAC6Dpdbo9Xp9qHaoCDaqdpdVIc1qcj0YAPmXq2HU4LFAhOIIaPAq5wlfEAIz5JteR2xvUMA1G2AmlPa63p%20eCXOuuMlNGd%20DuALQeDMOc6gLs5B2oWyn3txpdpK9-sAJmHvYra4T09nlqXNszOadq6F8avLdIB3PcD0ZDMAAYsyPDlTxKc9L07btb3iABmR9g1Hcd40nRMZ3yMC03DQR62I7MV2w9cO0EICQP3AByABJVAAB16OEXCtHgeBuHou1BXg71gkQ68e0wgBRKN4DIDDyzHF9cLfAiP3tX9KIApD5grFTGTEYRiIEqjAO3Xd9wIGCTzPb0gA)

Comment: Thanks, it seems clear to define `Option` like `type Option = OptionWithParamsArray|OptionWithParams;`